# Defining a constraints matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, python

I have a short question,

Would it be correct to define the following constraints:
$$
\begin{align*}
- L_0 - A_0 + L_1 &= 0, \\
- L_1 - A_1 + L_2 &= 0, \\
- L_2 - A_2 + L_3 &= 0, \\
 &\vdots \\
- L_{119} - A_{119} + L_{120} &= 0
\end{align*}
$$

Into a constraints matrix that looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
H = np.zeros((120, 240))
for i, p in zip(range(120), range(120)):
    for j in range(i, i+3):
        if j - i < 2:
            H[p][j] = -1
        else:
            H[p][j] = 1
```

Comment: It definitely gets you a $120\times 240$ matrix with $-1$, $-1$, and then $1$ in the $(i,i)$, $(i,i+1)$, and $(i,i+2)$ entries for $i = 0,\ldots,119$, but beyond that it's tough to say if what you're doing is correct. Are the $A_{i}$ known constants, or are they variables (slack, etc.) that you also want to solve for?

Comment: They are known constant, $-1 \leq A_i \leq 1$. So this should be the only thing to solve for.

Answer (score 1):

If the $A_{i}$ are unknown, I think the constraint system should be

\begin{equation*}
\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1
\end{array}\right)}_{120\times 241}\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{c}
L_{0}\\
L_{1}\\
L_{2}\\
\vdots \\
L_{120}\\
A_{0}\\
A_{1}\\
A_{2}\\
\vdots\\
A_{119}
\end{array}\right)}_{241\times 1} = \underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{array}\right)}_{120\times 1}
\end{equation*}

Otherwise, I think it should be

\begin{equation*}
\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
-1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1\\
\end{array}\right)}_{120 \times 121}\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{c}
L_{0}\\
L_{1}\\
\vdots\\
L_{119}\\
L_{120}
\end{array}\right)}_{121\times 1} = \underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{c}
A_{0}\\
A_{1}\\
\vdots\\
A_{119}
\end{array}\right)}_{120\times 1}
\end{equation*}

The way you're constructing your matrix, it seems like you're sort of mixing up the positions of the $A_{i}$ and the $L_{i}$.

Comment: Thank you. How come there are $121$ and $241$ columns respectively. Is it to account for the separate constraint on $L_0$

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the unknowns are either the $L_{0},\ldots,L_{120}$ (there are $121$ of them) in which case you $121$ variables subject to $120$ equality constraints; or $L_{0},\ldots,L_{120},A_{0},\ldots,A_{119}$, (there are $121+120 = 241$ of them) in which case you have $241$ variables still subject to  $120$ equality constraints

Comment: Yes. That is my understanding too.  This means my cost vector 'c' needs to be of size 241 too. Since the objective function is $max. \sum{cx}$ and $c$ is known, I now have my $120 p_i's$ and $120$ zeros in this vector. Would I have to add another $0$ here?

Comment: Right--so if the unknowns are $L_{0},\ldots,L_{120},A_{0},\ldots,A_{119}$, then I guess cost vector would be of the form  $(c_{1},c_{2},\ldots,c_{120},c_{121},\ldots,c_{241})$ where the $c_{121},\ldots,c_{241}$ are all zero if the $A_{i}$ don't figure in the cost. I guess my question is this: is your problem to maximize $\mathbf{c}^{T}\mathbf{L}$ subject to $L_{i} - L_{i+1} - A_{i} = 0$ for $i = 0,\ldots,119$ where $\mathbf{L} = (L_{0},\ldots,L_{120},A_{0},\ldots,A_{119})^{T}$?

Comment: My $\it{original}$ problem is: maximize $\textbf{c}^T\textbf{L}$ s.t. $L_t = L_{t-1} - A_{t-1}; t>1$ for $i=0,...,119$ where $\textbf{c}$ is a vector of $120$ prices, and $\textbf{L} = (A_0,...,A_{119})$